# switching users in byobu session

Tags: byobu

I launched a byobu session (tmux) and then tried to switch to a user called kommander `su - kommander`, it immediately prompted me with:

```
[Oh My Zsh] Would you like to check for updates?
Type Y to update oh-my-zsh:
```

Now I usually press <kbd>N</kbd> and everything is fine, but within the byobu session, when I press enter it just displays a "^M" character. I have no idea how to exit out if this prompt:

```
[Oh My Zsh] Would you like to check for updates?
Type Y to update oh-my-zsh: n^M
```

Answer (score 0):

The `^` character symbolizes the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key.
So `^M` just means press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> to exit out of the session.

Comment: I believe the `^M` is [the carriage-return character](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32001/what-is-m-and-how-do-i-get-rid-of-it), `CR`, [`\r` escape sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representation).